My stacked solana is taking too much time to unstake please anyone guide
My staked solana is nit getting unstake iam new in this field please anyone help

From the docs https://solana.com/staking#delegation-timing-considerations

The Solana protocol only allows stake tokens to finish changing state at the beginning of a new epoch. An epoch is approximately 2 days long.

This includes staking and unstaking where you are changing the state of your stake account.
In your case it's going from "active" to "deactivating" and finally you'll be able to get access to your staked tokens.
